# How to use transition with links on mozilla

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, css-transitions, mozilla

I have this code it should scale a link when the mouse is over it

**HTML**

```
<a class='subj' href='#'>English 2</a> </br>
```

**CSS**

```
    .subj{
    text-decoration:none;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out ;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.subj:hover { 
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2); 
}
```

This code works fine on both chrome and mozilla when the tag is `<p>` but when it is `<a>` it's not working on mozilla but it does on chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `.subj` `display` property to `inline-block`.

```css
.subj {
    text-decoration:none;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    display: inline-block;
}
```